# disable the validation for an specific button when using jQuery plugin: Validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-ajax

I'm using [jquery validation](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) with asp.net. The problem is, I have the search button and the comments button in the same form. When the users want to write a comment, the validation works perfect, but when the users want to make a search in the page, the required fields of the comments dosn't allow them.

So the question is how can I disable the validation for an specific button.

Thanks
roncansan

Answer (score 0):

Move the validation to the click event of the button and use [preventDefault](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/jQuery.Event#event.preventDefault.28.29)() if it fails validation.

```
$("#yourButtonId").click( function(event){
  if (formIsInvalidForSubmission)
     event.preventDefault();      
});
```